# Using wmd-editor with php

Tags: php, echo, wmd-editor

I'm using WMD-Editor (the modifed one at [github](https://github.com/ananthakumaran/wmd/)).
I'm using PHP as the backend. When I send the contents of Editor and try to echo them, they don't come out as expected.
I'm using $_POST to receive the data and then placing it into a mysql database.

For example when I try to make a list:

- Dummy
- Text
- This is

It displays it as -Dummy -Text -This is.
How can I make it output the list?

Comment: So that's where they've been keeping their WMDs; in github. I've always suspected as much, and I tried to warn them. "Insane!" they called me. "Shoo!" they said, and that was the last time I ever worked at Macdonalds. Welcome to SO, where we all sane!

Answer (score 0):

What you are receiving is text with Markdown syntax; to convert it into HTML you need [PhpMarkdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/). Just download the library, include it in your script and pass the text thru the `Markdown()` function (as explained in the '*In your own programs*' section).